# WAS8.5 - webcontainer poolsize settings for 500 concurrent users

Tags: jsf, concurrency, pool, ibm-was

I am working on a project which is developed using plain JSF with webservice backend and our target runtime is WAS8.5. It’s an internet application and being used by more that 500 concurrent users.

We are performing NFT testing with 150% load ie. 750+ concurrent users. From Introscope, I could see web container thread pool size is set as min&max value of 50. We feel web container thread pool size is blocking the concurrent loads we are trying to achieve. We are expecting experts suggestion for ThreadPoolModule and webcontainer poolsize settings in our WAS servers. (FYI: We have two WAS servers in our cluster)

Comment: Tuning depends on every application, so don't expect someone will give you settings for your application without knowing it and doing performance tests. You can use PMI and TPV built in the console to observe, if your pool is maxed out. Some basic tuning tips you can find [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tfullp_tun.html?lang=en), for more complex approach I'll rather need paid services.